# Matching a Multiline Regex Pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to `re.findall()` over multiple lines and have been unable to do so.  This is my regex.

````
rx = re.compile(r"```( )* test.+```", re.DOTALL)
list = rx.findall(string)
````

And all I am getting back is `[' ']`.  (Side note, the string is read in from a file.)  Can anyone explain what has gone wrong here?

I have also tried using `re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE` as flags and they didn't solve anything either.

Comment: Can you add some data for testing?

Comment: General hint from docs about `findall`: "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups". And there is one group here.

Comment: I know, but it is empty.  The string that I am trying to parse looks like this:
``` test
hi there
``` (with newlines, wouldn't show)

Comment: Your list doesn't look empty, it looks like it contains a single string consisting of a whitespace. That is exactly what the group in your pattern matches. Edit: Yup, that is exactly what I would expect when searching that string with this regexp. What are you trying to match?

Comment: What would a correct regex be to match the intended item?  I tried it in a regex tester for Python and it seemed to work.

Comment: See my answer. I'm not sure what that group was doing there in the first place, so it might not be what you need. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Butscher, `findall` will return only what is matched by the group in your pattern. In your case, that is a single white space. If you want to get the whole match returned, try

````
r'``` +test.+```'
````